# Modify Datatypes of columns of a table while reading it

Tags: pyspark

Consider I have a Table of csv format and it has columns

```
columnA -> IntegerType()
columnB -> IntegerType()
columnC -> IntegerType()
columnD -> IntegerType()
columnE -> IntegerType()
```

I want to read this csv file and while reading it I want to change the datatypes of the column to some other types.

I tried using StructType([])
What happnes is that if the struct has a different order than the order of column in the table then the column names are also modified. Can anyone suggest any way to do this in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

Define your `final schema of structtype` then we can make use of **schema** to dynamically cast the dataframe.

**`Explanation:`**

- `schema.dataType,schema.name` -> to get the field names dynamically and cast to datatype

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([('1','1.9','23.344')],['i','j','k'])
print("input Schema")
df.printSchema()

#final schema that required
sch = StructType([ \
    StructField("i",IntegerType(),True), \
      StructField("j",DecimalType(),True), \
        StructField("k",DoubleType(),True)
  ])

for f in sch.fields:
  df= df.withColumn(f"{f.name}",col(f"{f.name}").cast(f.dataType))

print("output Schema")
df.printSchema()
df.show(10,False)
#input Schema
#root
# |-- i: string (nullable = true)
# |-- j: string (nullable = true)
# |-- k: string (nullable = true)
#
#output Schema
#root
# |-- i: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- j: decimal(10,0) (nullable = true)
# |-- k: double (nullable = true)
#
#+---+---+------+
#|i  |j  |k     |
#+---+---+------+
#|1  |2  |23.344|
#+---+---+------+
```